# Magento error "Currency 'USD' not found"

Tags: magento-1.7, error, currency

This is happening only when I save, for a store view, the Romanian locale.
On this shop, the allowed currencies are US$, Romanian Leu and EURO.
I set Currency Rates for each allowed currency: if US$ is default currency then I have a specific currency rate, if Romanian Leu is default currency another specific currency rate and exactly the same thing for EURO.

I searched on google about this error but the only solution that I founded was to clear var/cache and var/session ... Well, that isn't a solution.

> a:5:{i:0;s:24:"Currency 'USD' not found";i:1;s:5065:"#0
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(576):
>   Zend_Currency->__construct('USD', Object(Zend_Locale))
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(233):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Locale->currency('RON')
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(238):
>   Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatTxt(0)
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(682):
>   Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->getOutputFormat()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php(168):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Locale->getJsPriceFormat()
>   /app/design/frontend/magento-boilerplate/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(69):
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View->getJsonConfig()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
>   include('/home/mediaswit...')
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/magent...')
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
>   /app/design/frontend/magento-boilerplate/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(51):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
>   include('/home/mediaswit...')
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/magent...')
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52):
>   Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController),
>   'no-route')
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75):
>   Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController),
>   'no-route')
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419):
>   Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>  /app/Mage.php(683):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>  /index.php(87): Mage::run('',
>   'store')

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: what version of magento are you using?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I am not sure if this is the bug but if you compare the Magento 1.8 and Magento 1.7 versions of the function currency in Mage_Core_Model_Local you will notice a reference to [a bug with Zend_Currency](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10038)

**Magento 1.7: Mage_Core_Model_Local->currency**

```
/**
 * Create Zend_Currency object for current locale
 *
 * @param   string $currency
 * @return  Zend_Currency
 */
public function currency($currency)
{
    Varien_Profiler::start('locale/currency');
    if (!isset(self::$_currencyCache[$this->getLocaleCode()][$currency])) {
        try {
            $currencyObject = new Zend_Currency($currency, $this->getLocale());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $currencyObject = new Zend_Currency($this->getCurrency(), $this->getLocale());
            $options = array(
                    'name'      => $currency,
                    'currency'  => $currency,
                    'symbol'    => $currency
            );
            $currencyObject->setFormat($options);
        }

        self::$_currencyCache[$this->getLocaleCode()][$currency] = $currencyObject;
    }
    Varien_Profiler::stop('locale/currency');
    return self::$_currencyCache[$this->getLocaleCode()][$currency];
}
```

**Magento 1.8: Mage_Core_Model_Local->currency**

```
/**
 * Create Zend_Currency object for current locale
 *
 * @param   string $currency
 * @return  Zend_Currency
 */
public function currency($currency)
{
    Varien_Profiler::start('locale/currency');
    if (!isset(self::$_currencyCache[$this->getLocaleCode()][$currency])) {
        $options = array();
        try {
            $currencyObject = new Zend_Currency($currency, $this->getLocale());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            /**
             * catch specific exceptions like "Currency 'USD' not found"
             * - back end falls with specific locals as Malaysia and etc.
             *
             * as we can see from Zend framework ticket
             * http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10038
             * zend team is not going to change it behaviour in the near time
             */
            $currencyObject = new Zend_Currency($currency);
            $options['name'] = $currency;
            $options['currency'] = $currency;
            $options['symbol'] = $currency;
        }

        $options = new Varien_Object($options);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('currency_display_options_forming', array(
            'currency_options' => $options,
            'base_code' => $currency
        ));

        $currencyObject->setFormat($options->toArray());
        self::$_currencyCache[$this->getLocaleCode()][$currency] = $currencyObject;
    }
    Varien_Profiler::stop('locale/currency');
    return self::$_currencyCache[$this->getLocaleCode()][$currency];
}
```

My suggestion would be to try updating the try catch to match that of Magento 1.8 (I know this is not the best solution and obviously I would not suggest editing the core files but adding a rewrite)